# Bad C code to test a error handler

Tags: c, unit-testing, error-handling

I am searching for "bad/broken" c code that I can use test a error handler on a mcu based system.

I am searching for code that will break during runtime.

So go crazy, what small pieces of code do you have in your back pocket that could be used to break a system. And should be handled by a error handler to avoid uncontrolled behaviour.

/Thanks

---

I will begin with a couple of examples.

Write to a null pointer

```
int* pointer = 0x0;
*pointer = 0xBAADC0DE;
```

Write a value to a pointer that is unvalid

```
int* pointer = 0xCAFEBABE;
*pointer = 0xDEADBEEF;
```

Jump to a unvalid function pointer

```
int (*fpBabe)() = 0xDEADBABE;
fpBabe();
```

So do you have some more bad things that you could throw at a error handler?

Comment: Does the error handler not come with sort of documentation that describes what types of error it can handle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make C++ crash without casting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556183/make-c-crash-without-casting)

Comment: @Oli This is for future reference, I think I will write one for a specific system. And since I am now a TTD guy. I am collection stuff that I can test this error handler with. So this is for tomorrow, but it is also kind on fun to see all the nasty answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide by zero (and simple math to get at it in case the compiler tries to optimize it away):

```
int i = argc;
return 34/(argc-i);
```

Try accessing a high mem address, as well as a low one:

```
char *v = ~0;
*v = '\0';
```

If you have a heap mgmt library, try freeing twice:

```
char *ptr = malloc(4096);
free(ptr); free(ptr);
```

Try allocating memory without abandon:

```
for(;;)
    malloc(4096);
```

Try to exhaust the stack:

```
int foo(int arg) { return foo(arg+1); }
int main(int a, char *v[]) { return foo(1); }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int f() { return f() + f(); }
int g() { return g(); }
int h() { while(1); }
```

Comment: @oli -- you are correct, but the OP's requrements are somewhat fuzzy. "`bad/broken` C code" covers a pretty broad range.

Comment: But the f() and g() are great tests :)

Comment: Well eternal loops like while(1) has to be handled by a watchdog and not a error handler. But the f() and g() blows the stack.

Comment: @Johan - perhaps you could describe what you mean by "error handler"?

Comment: For more advanced mcu:s there is hardware that we can use to capture this kind of errors, this hw in combination with some sw becomes a "error handler" and most of the time just reboots the system since you can't fix it in any other way. But it is good to know what it can handle and not to handle. And if there is any debug data that I can extract to make future bug searching easier. (Hope I don't have to thou).

Comment: There should be no difference between f() and g(), since computing the first summand is already taking indefinite time.

Comment: @Philip, the difference is that, in `g()`, the compiler might use tail-call optimization to avoid a recursive function call. So, `g()` might be equivalent to `f()`, in that it consumes infinite stack, or `g()` might be equivalent to `h()`, in that it consumes infinite time, but no stack.

Comment: @Rob: You are right regarding tail-call optimization in `g()`, but the same applies to `f()` as well. A smart compiler might recognize that in each call to `f()`, only the first summand is ever evaluated, and hence optimize away the `+f()` part, giving room for tail call optimization. Or am I too hypothetical again?

Answer (score 2):

Exhaust the stack by mutual recursion (might be harder to detect):

```
int f(void) { return g(); }
int g(void) { return f(); }
int main(void) { return f(); }
```

...or by funny signal handling:

```
void handler(int n) { raise(n); raise(n); }
int main(void) { signal(SIGINT, &handler); raise(SIGINT); return 0; }
```

Destroy the heap:

```
for (char *x = malloc(1); *x++ = 42;);
```

Destroy the heap and blame free():

```
char *x = malloc(1);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; x[i++] = 42);
free(x);   // free() will probably segfault
```

Answer (score 1):

Write past the end of a buffer:

```
 char dest[5];
 const char* src = "a bigger source";
 strcpy(dest,src);
```

or

```
 dest[5]='\0';
```

Comment: Well if you go backwards (or forward dpends on arch) just a couple of steps you can destroy things like the stackpointer, and then when we try to return from this function we have another fun bug...